# how to use third party plugins in the project using phonegap for crossplatform?

Tags: javascript, html

I can install the third party plugins from the phonegap library,these third party plugins has been installed using npm(Node Package Manager).But i couldn't properly use the third party plugins in my project rather default plugin.
Suggest an idea.

Comment: Why can't you properly use the third party plugins?

Comment: I didn't get any proper procedures,how to use third party plugins